# strace output: disabling abbreviation completely changes the output

Tags: strace

A normal `strace` call gave me this output:

```
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
```

I want to see the other terminal flags and tried `-v` and `-e abbrev=none`:

> Print  unabbreviated versions of environment, stat, termios, etc. calls.

But both options do not (just) show more but instead this:

```
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {c_iflags=0x5500, c_oflags=0x5, c_cflags=0xbf, c_lflags=0x8a3b, c_line=0, c_cc="\x03\x1c\x7f\x15\x04\x00\x01\x00\x11\x13\x1a\x00\x12\x0f\x17\x16\x00\x00\x00"}) = 0
```

Comment: What's you full `strace` command?

Comment: @cuonglm `strace -p 28406 -f -e abbrev=none`, attached to `bash`. No alias or function for `strace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/07a6399dd6ee7ca68d44d15cf020ea1fe8a15497/term.c#L49), those are the only behaviours available. Only for abbreviated output, the baud rate and states of those four flags are explicitly printed. Otherwise, the hexadecimal values are printed to provide you the gory details. You'll have to look for the termios flags [elsewhere](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html).

```c
if (abbrev(tcp)) {
    tprints("{");
    printxval(baud_options, tios.c_cflag & CBAUD, "B???");
    tprintf(" %sopost %sisig %sicanon %secho ...}",
        (tios.c_oflag & OPOST) ? "" : "-",
        (tios.c_lflag & ISIG) ? "" : "-",
        (tios.c_lflag & ICANON) ? "" : "-",
        (tios.c_lflag & ECHO) ? "" : "-");
    return;
}
tprintf("{c_iflags=%#lx, c_oflags=%#lx, ",
    (long) tios.c_iflag, (long) tios.c_oflag);
tprintf("c_cflags=%#lx, c_lflags=%#lx, ",
    (long) tios.c_cflag, (long) tios.c_lflag);
tprintf("c_line=%u, ", tios.c_line);
```